# Perl - Can't use Regex to replace 1's in tsv file

Tags: regex, perl, str-replace

I have a tab-delimited file that looks like this:

```
Sample  Beta Actin  GAPDH   Claudin     E-Cadherin
1   1840.055    893.08      1           6387.773
2   1862.971    48.335      1           6373.066
3   991.598     1           2434.882    1
```

I want to replace every instance of "1" with a letter "X"; but I do not want to affect longer number than contain the number 1. I tried:

```
open (FILE, $file);
while (<FILE>) {
    my $line = $_;
    chomp $line;
    my @c = split('\t', $line);
    foreach (@c) {
            $_ =~ s/^1$/X/g;
    }
    print $line, "\n";
}
```

But this does not change a single character. Why doesn't this solution work? If you can suggest a solution that works for my problem, I will up-vote your answer but I am more interested in understanding why the code I have posted fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're splitting the `$line` and modifying the parsed results.

However, you're just printing the original `$line` instead of rebuilding it from the modified values like so:

```
$line = join "\t", @c;
```

Could also just do in-place editing of each field using:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    s/(?:^|\t)\K1(?=\t|$)/X/g;
    print;
}

__DATA__
Sample  Beta Actin  GAPDH   Claudin E-Cadherin
1   1840.055    893.08  1   6387.773
2   1862.971    48.335  1   6373.066
3   991.598 1   2434.882    1
```

Outputs:

```
Sample  Beta Actin  GAPDH   Claudin E-Cadherin
X   1840.055    893.08  X   6387.773
2   1862.971    48.335  X   6373.066
3   991.598 X   2434.882    X
```